# ошибка при отправлении POST запроса 422 Typescript/ react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

как исправить ошибку 422, которую я получаю после нажатия на кнопку формы? подскажите, пожалуйста)

```js
файл service.ts

import api from "@/api/api";
import { NotificationCloseService } from "./types";

export const sendActionOnNotificationClose: NotificationCloseService = async ({
  userRole,
  hiddenActions,
}) => {
  await api.post(`/${userRole}/action/hide-action/${hiddenActions}`);
};
```

```html
файл types.ts

export enum UserActionType {
  onboarding = 'onboarding_display',
  whyLongCalculationsNotification = 'why_long_calculations_notification_display'
}

export interface NotificationCloseService {
    (params: {
      userRole: 'admin' | 'agent',
      hiddenActions: UserActionType
     }): Promise<void>;
}
```

Comment: Ошибка [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) приходит от сервера. Говорит о том, что сервер не смог обработать запрос корректно. Так что надо смотреть, что именно отправляеся, как обрабатывается на сервере и почему могла возникнуть данная ошибка.

Comment: я понимаю, что передаваемы данные прописаны некорректно, но как это исправить - не знаю

Comment: Что бы это исправить, надо знать спецификацию API, куда вы отправляете запрос. Какой правильный URL, какие данные надо передавать. Сравнить эти данные с тем, что передается. Проверить корректность переданных данных можно в инструментах разработчика(F12) на вкладке сеть(network). Без понимания, какой запрос ожидается, по какому адресу и что на самом деле отправляется, помочь практически не возможно. Собственно, что такое `api.post` можно только гадать(Наверное axios?)